# Redirect do codelgniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Estou querendo colocar um `alert` simples do *Javascript* no *Codelgniter*, estou tentando colocar esse alerta com uma função do *Codelgniter* que é `redirect`. Eu coloco para redirecionar a página, mas o `alert` não funcionar.

O que pode ser?

```
$data['categoria'] = $this->input->post('categoria');
$data['slug_categoria'] = $this->input->post('slug_categoria');
$this->db->insert('categorias', $data);
redirect('administracao/categorias');
echo "<script>alert('Inseridos!')</script>";
```

Como faço pra essa mensagem de alerta funcionar com o redirect? dessa maneira e de outra que já tentei não funciona.

Comment: Funcionou perfeito, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

***Explicação:***

***1)*** Independente da tecnologia usada na programação, não misture código PHP com Javascript;

***2)*** O [redirect](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)  que é um [helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) do *CodeIgniter*, tem como função redirecionar para o endereço especificado, e internamente seria um `header("Location: /administracao/categorias");` então, ele nem vai executar a última linha que é um código Javascript (siga recomendação item 1).). Veja código logo abaixo:

```
function redirect($uri = '', $method = 'location', $http_response_code = 302)
{
    if ( ! preg_match('#^https?://#i', $uri))
    {
        $uri = site_url($uri);
    }
    switch($method)
    {
        case 'refresh': 
            header("Refresh:0;url=".$uri);
            break;
        default: 
            header("Location: ".$uri, TRUE, $http_response_code);
            break;
    }
    exit;
}
```

***3)*** Solução:

No seu método antes do `redirect`, use um [`$this->session`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) com o método `flashdata`, que tem a finalidade de ficar ativo somente até a próxima requisição do servidor e logo após ele é eliminado automáticamente.

***Método:***

```
$data['categoria'] = $this->input->post('categoria');
$data['slug_categoria'] = $this->input->post('slug_categoria');
$this->db->insert('categorias', $data);
$this->session->set_flashdata('acaoform', 'Inseridos !!!.');
redirect('administracao/categorias');
```

***View***

```
<?php
    $acaoflash = $this->session->flashdata('acaoform');    
    if (isset($acaoflash) && $acaoflash!=''){
        echo "<script>alert('".$acaoflash."')</script>";
    }
?>
```

*Referências:*

- [Session Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)
- [URL Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)